# How to scroll / swipe image at the same time with text box in ngx-carousel?

Tags: html, css, angular, carousel

I build a slideshow using ngx-carousel in Angular and I would like to addapt the code in order to swipe the textbox at the same time with the image. Please note that the slideshow shows 3 slides on the page. I would like to show for each slide in the middle, the 2-nd one, a text box. I tried to implement two different slideshows but apparently I can't synchronize the text with the right image. Do you have any ideas how I could implement the requirement? I would appreciate a lot any help!

The html for the carousel

```
<div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide col-lg-12">
        <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
  </div>
```

And the component.ts:

```
export class CarouselCardComponent implements OnInit {
slides: Array<object>;

slideConfig = { infinite: true,
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              arrows: true,
              dots: true,
              autoplaySpeed: 2000,
              variableWidth: false,
              avadaptiveHeight: false,
              centerPadding: '100px',
              pauseOnFocus: true,
              pauseOnHover: true,
              touchMove: true,
            };
  ngOnInit(): void {

  this.slides = [
  {img: '../assets/1.jpg',
   text: 'AAA',
  },
  {img: '../assets/2.jpg',
  text: 'text1'
  },
  {img: '../assets/3.jpg',
   text: 'text2'
  }
];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

took me a time too but its easy.

```
<p>{{ slide.text }}</p>
```